# Missing operators in function recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function in which I should find missing operators between each value.

> For example, there is a number_list = [3,4,5,6] and I need to find by using operators an answer of 1. So it would be 3*4-5-6 = 1. I would like to make that firstly from 4 numbers it would become 3, then from 3 to 2 =, 2 to 1 and finally the last number len(number_list) = 1 would be compared to an answer which is going to be given. (All the traditional mathematical operator precedences are disobeyed. It is from left to right. Integers need to be in that specific order).

Code:

```
i = number_list[0]
j = number_list[1]

plus = int(i)+int(j) 
minus = int(i)-int(j)
multiply = int(i)*int(j)

if number_list == 1 or number_list == answer:
    return operator_list
else:
    operator_list.append('+')
    return get_operators(str(plus)+ number_list[2:], operator_list, 
    answer)

    operator_list.append('-')
    return get_operators(str(minus)+ number_list[2:], operator_list, 
    answer)

    operator_list.append('*')
    return get_operators(str(multiply)+ number_list[2:], operator_list, 
    answer)
```

Currently I'm struggling with changing the function operator values recursively.

Comment: How specifically does "All the traditional mathematical operator precedences are disobeyed" impact the evaluation of the expression?

Comment: Do the four integers given have to come in that specific order?  If so, the problem is shorter.

Comment: Pretty sure he means left-to-right ignoring operator precedence.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Your posted code seems to focus on one implementation detail, rather than any overarching structure for the problem attack.  This is fine for *your* purposes, but it leaves the question quite broad, essentially asking for a tutorial in recursion and problem analysis.  These are beyond the scope of Stack Overflow -- more in the range of a local tutor or problem-solving tutorial on line.

Comment: To simplify some of your planning, look at the `itertools` package.  You want to try inserting various permutations of the basic operators.  `itertools` will help you iterate through those permutations.

Comment: Yes, integers have to be in that specific order.

Comment: "All the traditional mathematical operator precedences are disobeyed" it means that if it is "-" and then "/" it would not be that division would be first and then we would make a substraction (as normally in mathematics). The sign which is most left has a priority.

Answer (score 0):

To keep this simple, I'm going to do the unthinkable and use `eval()` since the focus here seems to be on generating operator permutations recursively, not implementing the evaluator.  We could do something simple-minded and iterative just to explore the problem:

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*']

equation = "((3 {} 4) {} 5) {} 6"

for operator1 in operators:
    for operator2 in operators:
        for operator3 in operators:
            string = equation.format(operator1, operator2, operator3)

            if eval(string) == 1:
                print(string)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
((3 - 4) * 5) + 6
((3 * 4) - 5) - 6
```

I'm using the equation `"((3 {} 4) {} 5) {} 6"` to forcibly disobey normal precedence.  This is an artifact of my using `eval()`, you shouldn't need to do this with your own evaluator.  The above solution doesn't scale well, however.  To get a scalable iterative solution that's closer to a recursive one, we can use the *itertools* moduel as others have suggested:

```
from itertools import product

operators = ['+', '-', '*']

equation = "((3 {} 4) {} 5) {} 6"

n_digits = sum(character.isdigit() for character in equation)

for permutation in product(*([operators] * (n_digits - 1))):

    string = equation.format(*permutation)

    if eval(string) == 1:
        print(string)
```

**SAME OUTPUT AS ABOVE**

```
((3 - 4) * 5) + 6
((3 * 4) - 5) - 6
```

Now we just need to replace `product()` with our own recursive permutation function:

```
def permutations(operators, count):
    if count == 1:
        return [[operator] for operator in operators]

    return [[operator, *permutation] for operator in operators for permutation in permutations(operators, count - 1)]

operators = ['+', '-', '*']

equation = "((3 {} 4) {} 5) {} 6"

n_digits = sum(character.isdigit() for character in equation)

for permutation in permutations(operators, n_digits - 1):
    string = equation.format(*permutation)

    if eval(string) == 1:
        print(string)
```

**SAME OUTPUT AS ABOVE**

```
((3 - 4) * 5) + 6
((3 * 4) - 5) - 6
```

There are, of course, other ways to approach this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a simple abstract syntax tree:

```
import operator
from collections import deque
d = {'+':operator.add, '-':operator.sub, '*':operator.mul, '/':operator.truediv}
_d = {'+':lambda x:x, '-':lambda x:-1*x}

class Tree:
  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.op, self.left, self.right = args
  def evaluate(self) -> int:
     return d[self.op](getattr(self.left, 'evaluate', lambda :self.left)(), getattr(self.right, 'evaluate', lambda :self.right)())
  @classmethod
  def build_tree(cls, _stream):
     if len(_stream) == 1:
       return _stream[0]
     while len(_stream) > 1:
       a, _op, b = [_stream.popleft() for _ in range(3)]
       if _op in {'*', '/'}:
          _stream.appendleft(cls(_op, a, b))
       else:
          _stream = [cls('+', a, _d[_op](b) if not _stream else cls.build_tree(deque([_d[_op](b), *list(_stream)])))]
     return _stream[0]
```

---

```
def evaluate(l:list, to_val:int) -> str:
  def ops(_d, current = []):
     if len(current) == len(l) - 1:
        yield iter(current)
     else:
        for i in _d:
           yield from ops(_d, current+[i])
  for i in ops(d):
     exp = list(filter(None, [c for b in l for c in [b, next(i, None)]]))
     t = Tree.build_tree(deque(list(exp)))
     if t.evaluate() == to_val:
       yield ''.join(str(h) if isinstance(h, int) else h for h in exp)


print(list(evaluate([3, 4, 5, 6], 1)))
```

Output:

```
['3*4-5-6']
```

Edit: evaluating the expression by ignoring order of operations:

```
def compute(data):
  data = deque(data)
  while len(data) > 1:
    a, op, b, *_data = data
    data = deque(_data)
    data.appendleft(d[op](a, b))
  return data[0]
```

Then, simply update `evaluate`:

```
if compute(list(exp)) == to_val:
  ...
```

Output:

```
['3-4*5+6', '3*4-5-6']
```

Comment: How difficult would it be to get your code to provide the other solution '3-4*5+6' as well?  I.e. provide all the solutions to a given equation.

Comment: @cdlane Relatively simple. Please see my recent edit.